# how to call methods with variable in node.js

Tags: node.js

how to call methods with variable in node.js
this is so that ;

```
var file=require("./file");
var method=b;

file.method();
```

//output
    //error : TypeError: file.method is not a function

how to use it?

Comment: what your trying to do here? what is ./file in the require?

Comment: Your file object should have a method named b()...

Comment: file : module.exports = {
  index: function () {  },index2 :function {  } ,index3 : function () {   }  // url : url:3000/file/index   url:3000/file/index2  ....like this..

Comment: how to use it as file.method()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok try this then

```
//file.js
module.exports = { 
    index: function () { 
        console.log("index called");
    },
    index2 :function() { 
        console.log("index2 called");
    } ,
    index3 : function () { 
        console.log("index3 called");
    } 
};
```

then

```
app.get("file/:method",function (req,res)
{
    var method = req.params.name;

    var file = require('./file');

    file[method]();
}
```

Comment: method is not fixed , it is variable..  because I call via url as file/method

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("file/:method",function (req,res)
{

var file("./file");
var method=req.params.name;

file.method();
```

this is what ı want to tell